# extract data from a file based on another file

Tags: awk

I have two files named file_a and file_b. I would like to extract data from file_b based on the data of file_a.

file_a

```
1kps_2
1tgs
1kp3_1
```

file_b

```
PDB 1sih AA
PDB 1kps_2 AB
PDB 1kp3_1 CD
PDB 1sjy AA
```

Desired output

```
PDB 1kps_2 AB
    1tgs   not available
PDB 1kp3_1 CD
```

your help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You need to show what you tried so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{b[$2]=$0;next}{print $0 in b? b[$0]: $0 " not available"}' fileb filea
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file1 | while read aline;do grep $aline file2 || echo $aline not available;done
```

...should do what you want without awk.  Note this works in sh (or bash, but it copped some bashing lately ;)

If files are large then an awk script would probably/might be much more efficient. However depending on whether the files are sorted then it may not actually make any difference since the second part would have to always grep the entire file2 in order to ensure that a possible match was not 'above' the current position in file2.

An empty last line in file1 will also produce a 'not available' on a line by itself at the end.